# How to consume data from Apache Kafka in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have got the json using `kafka-avro console-consumer`. Now I want to get the json in a `spring-boot` console. What to do next?

Comment: Can u give the flow of how you are achieving to bring it from MySQL to kafka console? Are you reading the data from the MySQL using a producer and writing it to a Kafka topic ?

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/#five I hope this link helps you !!

Comment: You don't have JSON. You have deserialized Avro

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create a consumer:

```
@Service
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "myTopic-consumer-group")
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("Message: %s", message));
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also have to configure Avro deserializer. The message probably isn't a string

Comment: Can you help me , how to configure that in spring boot @cricket_007

Comment: @Vik it's not clear what you're currently setting on your spring property file. Please add to your question and what have you tried so far? Hint: how would you set the same property without spring?

Answer (score 0):

**@KafkaListener** annotation can be used to read messages from kafka topic.

Here is a working example of a class that reads Kafka messages:

```
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;

public class KafkaReader {

  private String latestMessage = "";

  @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
  public void receive(String payload) {
      latestMessage = payload;
  }

  public String getLatestMessage() {
      System.out.println("Message read from topic: \n" + latestMessage);

      // Code to format the message

      return latestMessage.trim();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done all these things. The problem is If I write the write the consumer command in terminal (_bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic demo-mysql-jdbc --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning_). It gives me the message. But I want to achieve the similar thing in eclipse console..

Comment: Hi Vikash,  Here is a fully working demo, developed by me, to show data streaming with kafka, spring boot and websocket - https://github.com/deargopinath/kafka-spring-boot-websocket  It has the code for showing kafka messages in console and on browser. Please let me know if it had helped.